# Output duplication

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have run into a issue as my outputs have been been duplicated.

I have a slight idea as to why it duplicates the way it does however I don't know how the issue is being caused.

Currently the output is duplicated by 3 (The amount of values that the array `gen_coms` contains.

The following snippets of code are what is related to this issue(Please disregard ALL comments in the code):

The First function:

```
 gen_coms = []
    def getCommands():
        for file in os.listdir(com_dir):
            if file.endswith(com_ext):
                global gen_coms
                a = gen_coms.append(file[:-len(com_ext)]) # Looks good however formats output as ['a','b','c'] is there a way to format it as 'a','b','c' or a,b,c ?
```

The 2nd function:

```
def genTerm():
while True:
    gin = raw_input('> ')
    for commands in gen_coms: # Prints out 3 vars. This didn't happen before but I am assuming thats because gen_coms now technically has a value of 3?
        if gin in gen_coms:
            print gin
        else:
            print('Unrecognized command!')
```

An example input/output to help show what the issue I am getting looks like:

```
> a # This is the input -> a
a  # Here down is output
a
a
```

The input `a` is entered and the correct output which is also a is printed only instead of the single time I would expect it has become 3. This isn't limited to just `a` but every output.

Non-Important side notes:

Sorry if the format of this question isn't the best, I am having a very hard time focusing and thinking in general at the moment due to lack of sleep and will make a edit correcting grammar, spelling, and overall layout in a minute or two.

Thank you as well for taking the time to read this lengthy and most likely repetitive question.

Comment: If you post a properly indented [mcve] you are more likely to get help. The code you posted will behave differently to the code you mean to ask about, because the indentation is wrong, and badly indented Python code does not work.

Comment: Why do you even have a `for` loop in the 2nd function?  The whole point of `gin in gen_coms` is that it checks the entire list.  You are repeating that check, and printing out an answer, as many times as there are elements in the list.

Comment: Either remove loop or after you `print gin`, add a `break`.

Comment: @khelwood What was provided is about as short as it can get (exempt for the coments) What part of the indentation is incorrect with the examples/snippets??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def genTerm():
    while True:
          gin = raw_input('> ')
          for commands in gen_coms: 
              if gin in gen_coms:
                 print gin
              else:
                 print('Unrecognized command!')
```

this behaviour is happening because of line 4 ad line 5 actually
let me explain since gen_coms length is 3 the loop is running three times here and in each iteration of for loop if condition is getting true and it prints first character each time.

so, that prints **a** thrice;

in line five replace gen_coms with commands.

Comment: Im so sorry I forgot to  accept your answer the day I asked this!

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the comments posted and looking into my code more, I have found a fix:

```
def genTerm():
    while True:
        gin = raw_input('> ')
        if gin in gen_coms:
            print gin
        else:
            print("Invalid command!")
```

This solves my problem, and makes the function shorter. Thank you to all who spent time looking into this.